# Nginx Reverse Proxy: servername.domain.com reverse to http://ip.add.res.s/location/App

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, https, centos6.5

I need a little help sorting out how to configure a reverse proxying load balancer in nginx. Basically, I have two web applications that live under subdirectories on Apache servers, /flavors/Chocolate and /flavors/Vanilla for example. This app runs on multiple servers for failover, so my list of upstream servers for Chocolate looks like this:

`upstream Chocolate {
   ip_hash;
   server 192.168.10.100;
   server 192.168.10.101;
   server 192.168.10.102;
 }`

Now, what I want to do is be able to take requests at the load balancer, 192.168.10.99, for **https://**chocolate.company.com and proxy pass them to the upstream servers on port 80 (http) to their actual locations at 192.168.10.xxx/flavors/Chocolate without rewriting the URI for the site from https://chocolate.company.com.

Here is what I have (that shoots out errors on me left and right):

`upstream Chocolate  {
   ip_hash;
   server 192.168.10.100;
   server 192.168.10.101;
   server 192.168.10.102;
 }
server {
        listen         80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        ### server port and name ###
        listen          chocolate.company.com:443;
        ssl             on;
        server_name     chocolate.company.com;`

```
    ### SSL log files ###
    access_log      logs/ssl-access.log;
    error_log       logs/ssl-error.log;

    ### SSL cert files ###
    ssl_certificate      /.pki/chocolate.company.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /.pki/chocolate.company.com.key;

    ### Add SSL specific settings here ###


    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

    ### We want full access to SSL via backend ###
    location / {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /flavors/Chocolate break;
            proxy_pass  http://chocolate.company.com;

            ### force timeouts if one of backend is died ##
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_50$

            ### Set headers ####
            proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            ### Most PHP, Python, Rails, Java App can use this header ###
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;##
            #This is better##
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header              Front-End-Https   on;


            ### By default we don't want to redirect it ####
            proxy_redirect     off;
}
```

Can anyone help me out here? I feel like I'm missing something really stupid and just not having that "eureka!" moment that I get after stewing on something a few and figured there's a chance one of y'all are quite a bit more accomplished with Nginx than me (which is just about not accomplished at all). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only problem is with the `proxy_pass` directive. You mention `http://chocolate.company.com` where you should in fact use the upstream group name here. I changed the name of the upstream group to better document the change:

```
# this is where all requests should be proxied to
upstream chocolate_upstream  {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.10.100;
    server 192.168.10.101;
    server 192.168.10.102;
}

# this is a redirect to send all requests to https instead - optional
server {
    listen         80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# this is the actual configuration
server {
    ### server port and name ###
    listen          chocolate.company.com:443;
    ssl             on;
    server_name     chocolate.company.com;

    ### log files for both access and errors ###
    access_log      logs/ssl-access.log;
    error_log       logs/ssl-error.log;

    ### SSL cert files ###
    ssl_certificate      /.pki/chocolate.company.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /.pki/chocolate.company.com.key;

    ### Add SSL specific settings here ###
    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers          RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;

    ### We want full access to SSL via backend ###
    location / {
         # this must use the name of the upstream group - mandatory
         # no need to rewrite but we can add the URI path here as well
         proxy_pass  http://chocolate_upstream/flavors/Chocolate;

         proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_50$
         proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
         proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         add_header              Front-End-Https   on;
         proxy_redirect     off;
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!